# Calling presentModalViewController from AppDelegate not working

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am working on with Facebook SDK 3.0 for my app (base SDK:iOS5) and using Scrumptious app (a sample app) as a tutorial. Where there is no open session for Facebook a login view controller is presented modally. But its not being presented modally. Here is the code;

```
- (void)showLoginView {
    UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navigationController topViewController]; // not nil, RootViewController kind of class
    UIViewController *modalViewController = [topViewController modalViewController]; // nil since not modalviewcontroller exists

    if (![modalViewController isKindOfClass:[FacebookLoginViewController class]]) {
        FacebookLoginViewController *loginViewController = [[FacebookLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FacebookLoginViewController" bundle:nil]; // allocated, no problem
        [topViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO]; // not working????

    } else {
        FacebookLoginViewController* loginViewController = (FacebookLoginViewController*)modalViewController;
        [loginViewController loginFailed];
    }
}
```

Details;

- showLoginView is being called from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and being called after the navigationController is assigned
- `RootViewController` of the navigationController's calls `viewDidLoad` method before `showLoginView` called
- in `showLoginView`, `topViewController` is not nil (it is what is should be: `RootViewController`)
- navigationController is kind of class UINavigationController (not custom)
- `loginViewController` (`FacebookLoginViewController`)'s `init` method is called, but not its `viewDidLoad` method)

Log Output:

2013-03-21 20:01:28.729 RootViewController: viewDidLoad

2013-03-21 20:01:28.735 FacebookLoginViewController: Allocated

Comment: presentModalViewController:animated: has been deprecated.  Try using presentViewController: instead.

Comment: still not presented..

Answer (score 5):

Try forcing your UI code to run on Main Thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [topViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your topViewController, declare an instance of FacebookLoginViewController.  `@property (nonatomic, strong) FacebookLoginViewController *fbVC;`  This will give that viewController a reference to the controller you want to present.  The reason it's allocating but not presenting, is because your topViewController is currently being asked to present an object it doesn't own.  You need to pass it ownership.

Add `topViewController.fbVC = loginViewController;`  and change `[topViewController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];`  to `[topViewController presentViewController:topViewController.fbVC animated:NO completion:nil];`

Comment: I have tried presentViewController:animated:completion:, no luck. I don't see why I should force the modal view controller though?

Comment: I assumed modalViewController was declared in your topViewController.  If it's not, declare a FacebookLoginViewController in your topViewController, and set it to loginViewController in your appDelegate, so your topViewController has a reference to it.

Comment: I am not supposed to declare it. The whole idea of appdelegate owning this part of code so that any viewcontroller can call this view.

Comment: Sure, but in that case the presenting view needs a reference to it, and should access it via the `MyAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`  method, and create a reference inside that viewController: `FacebookLoginViewController *fbVC = delegate.loginViewController;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you keep a reference to your Application's window, you should call `[self.window.rootViewController present...]`

Also note that it might not work when another VC is already presented modally (depends on your target iOS version - actually you should use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead of the methods using the "modal" wording)